# LocalStorage isn't shown after refreshing page

Tags: angular, google-chrome, browser

I'm currently developing an Angular 2 Web-Application.

When I open the Chrome Development-Tool (f12), I can see the localstorage from the localhost. But as soon as I refresh the page, the localstorage goes away from the list...

[Before refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIrlQ.png)

[After refreshing: The localstorage from the localhost isn't there anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94tiG.png)

Is is normal that the localstorage hides when refreshing the page?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the code you are using to set the localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this as well. After the page loads, close the Dev Tool and open it again, localStorage and sessionStorage should be available again.

Quickest way, after page reloads, hit F12 twice.

Comment: This could be a bug of Chrome Development-Tool. This should be the accepted answer :)